# SQL Server 2008 R2 query need guidance

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2008-r2

```
SELECT 
    A.First_Name, b.First_Name, A.DOB, B.DOB, A.Token, B.Token, 
    DATEDIFF(YEAR, A.DOB, B.DOB)                        -
    (CASE
       WHEN DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YEAR, A.DOB, B.DOB), A.DOB) > Getdate() 
         THEN 1                                        
         ELSE 0 END) 'Age Difference' 
FROM 
   Boys_details A , Girls_details B
WHERE
   a.Cast = 'brahmin'
   AND A.City = 'pune'
   AND a.Height >= B.Height
   AND a.Salary >= B.salary
```

Output:

```
Nilesh  Ruchita 1973-01-21  1964-12-01  9   89  -9
Nilesh  Smitha  1973-01-21  1976-07-30  9   77  3
Nilesh  Richa   1973-01-21  1974-04-21  9   2   1
```

I don't want minus values in output , but still its give as one of the condition like height and salary is satisfying but in case of age they failed. So one that fail in dont want to show them in o/p Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

how about it in a subquery?

```
SELECT  *
FROM
        (
            SELECT  A.First_Name,
                    b.First_Name,
                    A.DOB,
                    B.DOB,
                    A.Token,
                    B.Token, 
                    DATEDIFF(YEAR,A.DOB,B.DOB) -
                        (CASE WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,A.DOB,B.DOB),A.DOB)> Getdate() 
                                THEN 1                                        
                                ELSE 0 
                        END) AS [Age Difference] 
            from    Boys_details A , 
                    Girls_details B
            where   a.Cast='brahmin' and 
                    A.City='pune' and 
                    a.Height >= B.Height and 
                    a.Salary>=B.salary
        ) s
WHERE [Age Difference] >= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add your case statement to your where clause:

```
SELECT 
    A.First_Name, b.First_Name, A.DOB, B.DOB, A.Token, B.Token, 
    DATEDIFF(YEAR, A.DOB, B.DOB)                        -
    (CASE
       WHEN DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YEAR, A.DOB, B.DOB), A.DOB) > Getdate() 
         THEN 1                                        
         ELSE 0 END) 'Age Difference' 
FROM 
  Boys_details A , Girls_details B
WHERE
   a.Cast = 'brahmin'
   AND A.City = 'pune'
   AND a.Height >= B.Height
   AND a.Salary >= B.salary
   AND (CASE WHEN DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YEAR, A.DOB, B.DOB), A.DOB) > Getdate() 
     THEN 1                                        
     ELSE 0 END) => 0
```